# Добавление колонки с результатом в datagridview

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview, textbox

У меня есть текстовый файл, который представляет базу данных, как программно можно создать вычисляемую колонку в которой будет выводиться прибыль товара, как sold*coast?

```
 OleDbConnection StrCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=file;Extended Properties=text");

    DataSet AllTables;
 
 
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
  
    }
 
    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index); //удаление
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите строку для удаления.", "Ошибка.");
        }
    }
 
  
 
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
       OleDbConnection StrCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=file;Extended Properties=text");
        //Строка для выборки данных
        string Select1 = "SELECT * FROM [bd.txt]";
        //Создание объекта Command
        OleDbCommand comand1 = new OleDbCommand(Select1, StrCon);
        //Определяем объект Adapter для взаимодействия с источником данных
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(comand1);
        //Определяем объект DataSet
        DataSet AllTables = new DataSet();
        //Открываем подключение
        StrCon.Open();
        //Заполняем DataSet таблицей из источника данных
        adapter1.Fill(AllTables);
       
        //Заполняем обект datagridview для отображения данных на форме
        dataGridView1.DataSource = AllTables.Tables[0];
        StrCon.Close();
        
    }
 
    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult iExit;
        iExit = MessageBox.Show("Подтвердите, что Вы хотите выйти", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if(iExit == DialogResult.Yes) {Application.Exit();}
        
    }
 
    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = product.Text; // столбец Name
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = department.Text; // Age
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = sold.Text; // Programmer
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = stock.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = coast.Text;          
        }
        else
        {
        }
        /*AddForm af = new AddForm();
        af.Owner = this;
        af.Show();*/
 
    }
 
    
    private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
 
    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchForm sf = new SearchForm();
        sf.Owner = this;
        sf.Show();
    }
 
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"bd.txt", false, Encoding.Default);
            //Добавление имен столбцов
           for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                sw.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText);
                if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                    sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                    if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                        sw.Write(",");
                }
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
 
    private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        
        
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = product.Text; 
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = department.Text; 
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = sold.Text; 
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = stock.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = coast.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите строку для редактирования.", "Ошибка.");
        }
    }
 
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            product.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            department.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            sold.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            stock.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            coast.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
           
        }
        catch
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Класс модели создаете со всеми нужными свойсвами + доп.свойство `public double Profit => Sold *Cost;`. Читаете файл, формируете коллекцию экземпляров этого класса, а затем привязываете эту коллекцию к DGV.

Comment: так, а можете программно это продемонстрировать, т.к. с моделью классов все понятно, а вот дальше не совсем

Comment: `bd.txt` покажите, тогда что-нибудь напишу в ответ.

Comment: @Bulson                       Products,Department,Sold,Stock,Coast
                                     Apple,Fruits,25,300,3
                                     Meat,Gastronomia,60,100,10
                                     Banana,Fruits,40,60,4

Comment: Хорошо. Ждите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: пример]

Создаем класс модели

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Sold { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public int Profit => Sold * Cost;
}
```

кстати "стоимость" это `Cost`, а `Coast` это "побережье"

Создадим подсобный класс для работы с файлом (я написал только чтение)

```
class CsvService
{
    private readonly string _pathToFile;

    public CsvService(string pathToFile)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToFile))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pathToFile));
        }
        _pathToFile = pathToFile;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> ReadProductsFile()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_pathToFile) == false)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Файл {_pathToFile} не найден");
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var result = new List<Product>();
        try
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(_pathToFile)
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                        .Select(l => l.Split(','));

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var p = new Product
                {
                    Name = line[0],
                    Department = line[1],
                    Sold = int.TryParse(line[2], out int sold) ? sold : 0,
                    Stock = int.TryParse(line[3], out int stock) ? stock : 0,
                    Cost = int.TryParse(line[4], out int cost) ? cost : 0,
                };

                result.Add(p);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Читаем такой файл

```
Products,Department,Sold,Stock,Cost
Apple,Fruits,25,300,3
Meat,Gastronomia,60,100,10
Banana,Fruits,40,60,4
```

Код в форме такой

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //источник данных для DGV
    private BindingSource _bsProducts;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
        _buttonLoad.Click += ButtonLoad_Click;
        _buttonMaxProfit.Click += ButtonMaxProfit_Click;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //привязkа к DGV
        _bsProducts = new BindingSource();
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _bsProducts;
    }

    private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //создаем сервис чтения данных из файла
        var service = new CsvService("bd.txt");
        //читаем и заполняем источник данных для DGV
        service.ReadProductsFile()
                              .ToList()
                              .ForEach(p => _bsProducts.Add(p));
    }

    private void ButtonMaxProfit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bsProducts.Count == 0) return;

        var product = _bsProducts.List.OfType<Product>()
                       .OrderByDescending(p => p.Profit)
                       .First();

        _textBoxOutput.Text = $"{product.Name}: {product.Profit.ToString("c2")}";
            
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а можете еще подсказать как среди получившейся прибыли найти максимальную и вывести при нажатии кнопки в texBox?

Comment: Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Готово.........

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, все работает

Comment: Подскажите, а как можно найти именно отдел с максимальной прибылью и вывести его в тот же textBox?

Comment: Переменная `product` содержит и отдел тоже.

Comment: а если несколько товаров находится в одном отделе , то как вывести их сумму, а в product находится информация только об одном товаре

Comment: Я извиняюсь, вы галкой не отметили мой ответ вам, а все продолжаете засыпать меня вопросами. У вас совесть есть?

Comment: Извините, отметила