# Как можно реализовать чтение данных из текстового файла? далее как создать массив персон?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Person
{
    class Person
    {
        //свойства

        public string LastName { get; }    
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Patronymic { get; }
        private bool Gender { get; } /* 0 - male, 1 - female */
        public DateTime Birthday { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public int Weight { get; }
        public int Age { get; }
    
        //методы

        public int Сalculate_age(DateTime Birtday)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            return now.Year - Birthday.Year - (now.Month > Birthday.Month || now.Month == Birthday.Month && now.Day >= Birthday.Day ? 0 : 1);
        }

        public Person(string LastName, string Name, string Patronymic, bool Gender, DateTime Birthday, int Height, int Weight, int Age)
        {
            this.LastName = LastName;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Patronymic = Patronymic;
            this.Gender = Gender;
            this.Birthday = Birthday;
            this.Height = Height;
            this.Weight = Weight;
            this.Age = Age;
        }

        public static Person Parse(string text) // считываем информацию из файла 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "C:\\Users\\1392680\\source\\repos\\C#\\ООП_1\\1_work.txt";
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@path);
            //Person person_1 = new Person(file[0], file[1], file[2],file[3], file[4], file[5], file[6], file[7]);
            //public Person LastName = file[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Данные из файла:

```
Табаков 
Валерий
Филиппович
0
19.11.2001
186
83
Шпак
Елена 
Антоновна
1
25.06.1988
173
72
Левченко 
Лев 
Даниилович
0
07.08.2000
195
89
Каблукова 
Людмила
Олеговна
1
27.01.1997
188
76
Илларионов 
Тимофей
Сергеевич
0
25.06.2001
190
83
```

Comment: Мы ведь с вами говорили про картинки... Все, что является текстом - прикладывайте в виде текста. Как по-вашему сейчас должны люди помогать вам? Списывать вручную все с картинки?

Comment: Такой файл не годится. Одна строка должна содержать данные на одного человека, каждое свойство должно отделяться, например запятой (csv - файл). Чтение/запись файла должны быть реализованы в другом классе согласно принципу единственной ответственности. Пример чтения подобного файла можете найти в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216983/222542)

Comment: Ну прочитать именно такой бесмысленный формат весьма просто, надо лишь разбить его на равные части (набросал небольшой [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ThKNEd)), НО будь там хоть на одну строчку больше/меньше, то все, вы получаете кашу, по этой причине нужно использовать какие либо разделители, либо еще лучше, готовые форматы (JSON, XML, CSV и др.).

Comment: А еще есть базы данных. Но здесь вполне [справится обычный JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0). Вы уверены, что вам именно такой формат файла нужен как сейчас?